# How do I extract an event handler to another file and still have access to sender and args?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I attached an event handler to Entity Framework's SavingChanges event. Now, I found out I need to attach the same event handler somewhere else in the solution. Both situations (maybe even more if we dig deeper) require the same code so it makes sense to extract to a method and call the same method from multiple event handlers.

The method body includes references to the sender object and eventargs. How do I pass these parameters to the method, even when it's in its own class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender and event arguments should be part of your method signature and will be passed to the method you are writing when the event is fired. So the variables are defined as parameters to your event handler, and the values for those will be sent by the event trigger.

```
// I don't know what the proper signature is for a SavingChanges event handler
public class EventHandlers
{
    public static void SavingChangesHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
      // do something with sender and args here
    }
}


// in your other code
SomeObject.SavingChanges += EventHandlers.SavingChangesHandler;
```